# ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 1: Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a database named "crea" with a table named "assets" and in this table i have 11 column named (name,description,assetType,local,temporary,data,id,create_time,access_time,asset_flags,CreatorID)

I also have a directory folder with many picture in .jp2 format (xxxx.jp2)

What im trying to do is to bulk insert these picture in the table "assets" of my database, so i decided to do it with 2 shell scripts, the both are in the directory with the pictures.

When i launch ./assetadd.sh from the terminal, i get this error from MySQL :

```
ERROR 1048 (23000) at line 1: Column 'data' cannot be null
```

I checked many time and im sure that the column 'data' isnt NULL (Type: LONGBLOB Binaries Null: NO), so i really dont understand why i get this error.

Help will be apreciated. Thank you

***- Script 1 : assetsadd.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$(pwd)
find $path/ -type f \( -iname *.jp2 \) -exec ./insertjp2.sh {} \;

echo "finished!!"
```

***- Script 2 : insertjp2.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash

user="crea"
password="crea"
database="crea"
dbhost="localhost"
creator="crea"

param=$@
basenam=${param##*/}
filenam=${basenam%.*}

MYSQL=`/usr/bin/mysql -u$user -p$password -D$database -e"INSERT INTO assets (name,description,assetType,local,temporary,data,id,create_time,access_time​,asset_flags,CreatorID) VALUES ('$filenam','$filenam',0,0,0,LOAD_FILE('$param'),'$filenam',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),1325304546,0,'$creator' );"`

echo $param >> assetadd.log
echo $MYSQL
```

Comment: Any files with ' in their name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for LOAD_FILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

> Reads the file and returns the file contents as a string. To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function returns NULL.

It looks like at the very least, you are not specifying the full path to the file name.